# Navigating to the Nested child Attribute and Merge with the another Element

Tags: xslt

Here i am stuck with the XSLT transformation as i am very new and started learning.

Input XML

```
<SHOW_LIST>
<SHOW ID="12345">
    <SHOW_INFO>xxx</SHOW_INFO>
    <SHOW_ELEMENT_LIST>
        <SHOW_ELEMENT ID="1">  
            <SHOW_ELEMENT_LIST>
                <SHOW_ELEMENT ID="12345678"></SHOW_ELEMENT>
            </SHOW_ELEMENT_LIST>
        </SHOW_ELEMENT>
        <SHOW_ELEMENT ID="2">  
            <SHOW_ELEMENT_LIST>
                <SHOW_ELEMENT ID="12345666"></SHOW_ELEMENT>
            </SHOW_ELEMENT_LIST>
        </SHOW_ELEMENT>
    </SHOW_ELEMENT_LIST>
    <SECONDARY_ELEMENT_LIST/>
    <ALTERNATIVE_SHOW_LIST>
        <SHOW ID="54321">
            <SHOW_INFO>xxxa</SHOW_INFO>
            <SHOW_ELEMENT_LIST>
                <SHOW_ELEMENT ID="3">  </SHOW_ELEMENT>
                <SHOW_ELEMENT ID="4">  </SHOW_ELEMENT>
                <SHOW_ELEMENT ID="5">  </SHOW_ELEMENT>
            </SHOW_ELEMENT_LIST>
            <SECONDARY_ELEMENT_LIST/>
        </SHOW>
        <SHOW ID="54322">
            <SHOW_INFO>xxxb</SHOW_INFO>
            <SHOW_ELEMENT_LIST>
                <SHOW_ELEMENT ID="6">  </SHOW_ELEMENT>
                <SHOW_ELEMENT ID="7">  </SHOW_ELEMENT>
            </SHOW_ELEMENT_LIST>
            <SECONDARY_ELEMENT_LIST/>
        </SHOW>
    </ALTERNATIVE_SHOW_LIST>
</SHOW>
```

OUTPUT XML :

```
<SHOW_LIST>
    <SHOW ID="12345">
        <SHOW_INFO>xxx</SHOW_INFO>
        <SHOW_ELEMENT_LIST>
            <SHOW_ELEMENT ID="1">  </SHOW_ELEMENT>
            <SHOW_ELEMENT ID="2">  </SHOW_ELEMENT>
            <SHOW_ELEMENT ID="3">  </SHOW_ELEMENT>
            <SHOW_ELEMENT ID="4">  </SHOW_ELEMENT>
            <SHOW_ELEMENT ID="5">  </SHOW_ELEMENT>
            <SHOW_ELEMENT ID="6">  </SHOW_ELEMENT>
            <SHOW_ELEMENT ID="7">  </SHOW_ELEMENT>
        </SHOW_ELEMENT_LIST>
        <SECONDARY_ELEMENT_LIST/>
        <ALTERNATIVE_SHOW_LIST>
            <SHOW ID="54321">
                <SHOW_INFO>xxxa</SHOW_INFO>
                <SECONDARY_ELEMENT_LIST/>
            </SHOW>
            <SHOW ID="54322">
                <SHOW_INFO>xxxb</SHOW_INFO>
                <SECONDARY_ELEMENT_LIST/>
            </SHOW>
        </ALTERNATIVE_SHOW_LIST>
    </SHOW>
</SHOW_LIST>
```

I am able to navigate till Alternative_show_list and couldnt copy the SHOW_ELEMENTS and merge with the main SHOW_ELEMENT_LIST.

Anyone kindly help me in performing this

Another output of the same input file

```
<SHOW_LIST>
    <SHOW ID="12345">
        <SHOW_INFO>xxx</SHOW_INFO>
        <SHOW_ELEMENT_LIST>
            <SHOW_ELEMENT ID="1">  </SHOW_ELEMENT>
            <SHOW_ELEMENT ID="2">  </SHOW_ELEMENT>
            <SHOW_ELEMENT ID="3">  </SHOW_ELEMENT>
            <SHOW_ELEMENT ID="4">  </SHOW_ELEMENT>
            <SHOW_ELEMENT ID="5">  </SHOW_ELEMENT>
            <SHOW_ELEMENT ID="6">  </SHOW_ELEMENT>
            <SHOW_ELEMENT ID="7">  </SHOW_ELEMENT>
        </SHOW_ELEMENT_LIST>
        <SECONDARY_ELEMENT_LIST/>
     </SHOW>
</SHOW_LIST>
```

Now i am trying for this kind of output.

New Output XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SHOW_LIST>
   <SHOW ID="12345">
      <SHOW_INFO>xxx</SHOW_INFO>
      <SHOW_ELEMENT_LIST>
        <SHOW_ELEMENT ID="1">  
                <SHOW_ELEMENT_LIST>
                    <SHOW_ELEMENT ID="12345678"></SHOW_ELEMENT>
                </SHOW_ELEMENT_LIST>
            </SHOW_ELEMENT>
            <SHOW_ELEMENT ID="2">  
                <SHOW_ELEMENT_LIST>
                    <SHOW_ELEMENT ID="12345666"></SHOW_ELEMENT>
                </SHOW_ELEMENT_LIST>
            </SHOW_ELEMENT>
         <SHOW_ELEMENT ID="3"/>
         <SHOW_ELEMENT ID="4"/>
         <SHOW_ELEMENT ID="5"/>
         <SHOW_ELEMENT ID="6"/>
         <SHOW_ELEMENT ID="7"/>
      </SHOW_ELEMENT_LIST>
      <SECONDARY_ELEMENT_LIST/>
    </SHOW>
</SHOW_LIST>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simple stylesheet will do the trick:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <!-- identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- get all the SHOW_ELEMENT nodes -->
    <xsl:template match="SHOW//SHOW_ELEMENT_LIST[not(ancestor::ALTERNATIVE_SHOW_LIST)]">
        <SHOW_ELEMENT_LIST>
            <xsl:copy-of select="..//SHOW_ELEMENT"/>
        </SHOW_ELEMENT_LIST>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- delete all SHOW_ELEMENT_LIST under ALTERNATIVE_SHOW_LIST -->
    <xsl:template match="SHOW//SHOW_ELEMENT_LIST[ancestor::ALTERNATIVE_SHOW_LIST]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Joel. I am seeing the desired output. Can you please help me in understanding this                                                                                    <xsl:template match="SHOW//SHOW_ELEMENT_LIST[not(ancestor::ALTERNATIVE_SHOW_LIST)]"

Comment: It means match the descendants `SHOW_ELEMENT_LIST` (which do not have an ancestor `ALTERNATIVE_SHOW_LIST`) of the node `SHOW`

Comment: yeah its pretty clear with this statement. Thank you very much. one more question with the next statement.  <xsl:template match="SHOW//SHOW_ELEMENT_LIST[ancestor::ALTERNATIVE_SHOW_LIST]"/>.     This means it matches the descendants of SHOW_ELEMENT_LIST(which have an ancestor ALTERNATIVE_SHOW_LIST).  But howcome this deletes, just we were matching the list and nothing doing.  This might be a silly question , but i dont have an idea :-( . I am very much interested to learn and keen on XSLT so asking . Please explain

Comment: It means match the descendants `SHOW_ELEMENT_LIST` (which HAS an ancestor `ALTERNATIVE_SHOW_LIST`) of the node `SHOW`. With the template match being empty, It will delete the matched node.

Comment: Hi @Joel M. Lamsen, I just wanted to try different output like below.

Comment: <SHOW_LIST>
    <SHOW ID="12345">
        <SHOW_INFO>xxx</SHOW_INFO>
        <SHOW_ELEMENT_LIST>
            <SHOW_ELEMENT ID="1">  </SHOW_ELEMENT>
            <SHOW_ELEMENT ID="2">  </SHOW_ELEMENT>
            <SHOW_ELEMENT ID="3">  </SHOW_ELEMENT>
            <SHOW_ELEMENT ID="4">  </SHOW_ELEMENT>
            <SHOW_ELEMENT ID="5">  </SHOW_ELEMENT>
            <SHOW_ELEMENT ID="6">  </SHOW_ELEMENT>
            <SHOW_ELEMENT ID="7">  </SHOW_ELEMENT>
        </SHOW_ELEMENT_LIST>
        <SECONDARY_ELEMENT_LIST/>
     </SHOW>
</SHOW_LIST>

Comment: Sorry i couldnt format properly in the comment section

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="ALTERNATIVE_SCHEDULE_LIST"/>
```

This helps for the second output XML to delete the ATERNATIVE_SCHEDULE_LIST element.
Please correct me if there is any other solution

Comment: If you mean `<xsl:template match="ALTERNATIVE_SHOW_LIST"/>` as your second template, that should work fine.

Comment: Hi @Joel M. Lamsen, When i am trying for another inputXML of same type, i am failing to get the right output xml :-(.

Comment: I modified the Input XML . Here the SHOW_ELEMENT Ids has again the Sub lists with SHOW_ELEMENT ID. With the given Tranformation , the output contains the sub SHOW_ELEMENT ids also along with the main. I am trying to get the same output containing the main SHOW_ELEMENT ids 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 but shouldnt include the sub SHOW_ELEMENT ids like 12345678 and 12345666. 
 
Hi @Joel M. Lamsen, can you please give a simple logic change in the above transformation

Comment: Please see my answer here (http://xsltransform.net/bdxtqo). Notice that I changed xsl:copy-of to xsl:apply-templates

Comment: Yeah got it. Not only i want to "delete all SHOW_ELEMENT_LIST under ALTERNATIVE_SHOW_LIST". I need to completely delete the elements under ALTERNATIVE_SHOW_LIST. This i achieved earlier by using this <xsl:template match="ALTERNATIVE_SCHEDULE_LIST"/>. But now this is not working

Comment: Hi @JoelM.Lamsen, Now i am trying for different kind of XML, where i added that in the above as New Output XML. i tried with the below transformation  <xsl:template match="SCHEDULE//SCHEDULE_ELEMENT_LIST[not(ancestor::ALTERNATIVE_SCHEDULE_LIST)] and not(descendant::SCHEDULE_ELEMENT_LIST)">. But later not getting whether to use copy or apply :-(

Comment: Hi @JoelM.Lamsen, Really very much thankful for your kind help in learning XSLT :-)

Comment: You should really look into the basic tutorials in XSLT. You have to establish the basics before moving forward.